# Android camera app to add EXIF keyword tags at capture time

Tags: android, camera, exif

I am looking for an Android camera app that allows me to easily add tags directly after I took a photo. My ideal workflow would be:

- Open app
- Take photo
- Directly type in several tags related to the photo

  - Bonus points if I can also add the EXIF description
  - Tags must end up in the EXIF keywords field
- Close app

I found [this other question on Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/37503/327200), but the answers are outdated and didn't do exactly what the OP asked anyway.

### What I've tried

- I've used the Signal "note to self" functionality with the hope that I could extract the image + text and move everything to the right EXIF tags later with a script. I didn't succeed getting the images out of Signal.
- I've tried Lightroom, but there I had to:

  - take a picture
  - go to LR edit view
  - find the photo just taken
  - click on it
  - go to Info
  - and then add keywords.
  - I am looking for a more direct approach: take photo, directly write 2-3 keywords.

Comment: You can use Lightroom, but you should enter description, keywords by hand

Comment: Yes, but that's not very different from using any EXIF editing app on photos that are taken by the stock camera app. Just tried LR on Android, and I can take a picture, then have to go to LR edit view, find the photo just taken, click on it, go to Info, and then I can  add keywords. I am looking for a more direct approach: take photo, directly write 2-3 keywords.

Comment: One more thing about LR which may be a plus for you: RAW. And one more, if you have Adobe subscription you can sync the photos with your desktop LR.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. The syncing part (of all kinds of files on my phone) is taken care of by another app (Foldersync). The RAW support is also offered by my stock camera app. I am really just searching for user friendly entry of EXIF keywords directly after taking the photo.

Comment: It looks like you want to use any EXIF app and then automatize its tagging with e.g. Tasker. I doubt there's anything that would do that as a single application.

Comment: How would that work in Tasker? Can it call a certain part of an application after I take a photo? I just want to get the opportunity to add a keyword manually when I take a photo. It's almost similar to taking a photo in a messaging app and adding a caption in the fly before pressing send. Unfortunately in that case the caption is noy stored in Exif, otherwise that would be an option.